# rpmbuild: Can I set a variable to truncated hostname and force lowercase

Tags: bash, rpmbuild

So I can do this sort of thing in bash pretty easily, using something like:

```
HOSTNAME=`hostname -s`
SHORTHOST=${HOSTNAME%??}
HOST=$( echo "$SHORTHOST" | tr -s  '[:upper:]'  '[:lower:]' )
```

There may be better ways to do this but it does work.

The real question is if there's a way to set this in a variable in the spec file?

Or should I simply play with this stuff in the %post?

Answer (score 2):

This question is tagged `bash`.

If you are actually using bash, then `HOSTNAME` is already defined.  To convert it to lower case, just use `${HOSTNAME,,}`

Thus, to get SHORTHOST in lower-case:

```
SHORTHOST=${HOSTNAME%??}
echo "${SHORTHOST,,}"
```

If we not running under bash, then we have to use some utility to convert to lower case.  While `tr` is widely available, `sed` has the advantage of being unicode-safe:

```
HOST="$(echo "${shorthost}" | sed 's/.*/\L&/')"
```

Or, putting it all together for a non-bash shell:

```
HOST="$(hostname -s | sed 's/..$//; s/.*/\L&/')"
```

If you are using a bash older than version 4 (this means Mac OSX), then use the non-bash method.

Comment: I think in his case he is looking for `${SHORTHOST,,}`

Comment: Inside the `rpmwhatever.spec` is just a series of `bash` (or shell) commands (with a few rpm specific extensions). `SHORTHOST` is just a normal variable with the last 2 chars chopped off. That's why I think he actually wants (the contents of) `SHORTHOST` lowercase (although we both know the order he converts to lowercase is unimportant `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you!  I fixed the typo and updated to handle SHORTHOST both for bash and non-bash.

Comment: Bash versions earlier than v4 doesn't support `${var,,}` and `${var^^}`.

Comment: @alvits That is true. I updated the answer to mention that.  Bash 4.0 was released in 2009.  The only OS that I am aware of that still uses bash 3.x is OSX.  (Correct me if you know of others.)

Comment: It's misleading to suggest that the contents of a .spec file is mostly shell commands. There are *sections* composed of shell commands, but outside of those sections (importantly, including the areas where package-specific variables are defined), it's all syntax native to RPM.

Answer (score 0):

You can run bash commands with `%()` or you can launch `rpmbuild` with a script that `--define`s the variable computed in bash. Both will have advantages and disadvantages.